# strange behaviour of $http post request with header

Tags: c#, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to post data with header in angularJs.

If I post data without header then I'm able to get data on server side.

```
return $http.post('http://localhost:53646/Login', data, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" } }
              ).then(function (response) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log(response.data);
                  return response.data;
              }, function (error) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log(error);
              });
```

But when I post data with custom header, then I'm not getting Both header and data.

```
return $http.post('http://localhost:53646/Login', data, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Authorization":" Basic a3VtYXW1pdCsxQHJhbm9zeXMuY29tOlBhc3N3b3JkQDEyMzpJb3NBcHA" } }
              ).then(function (response) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log(response.data);
                  return response.data;
              }, function (error) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log(error);
              });
```

Comment: What is the actual error you receive? Is the ASP.NET endpoint receiving the request?

Comment: Is it for single request or all requests?

Comment: Why should not you use common auth header? like 
 $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "Pass data here";
return $http.post('http://localhost:53646/Login', data, { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"} }
              ).then(function (response) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log(response.data);
                  return response.data;
              }, function (error) {
                  debugger;
                  console.log(error);
              });

Comment: @ShridharMali: for all request. I have tried `Authorization` header too.

Comment: @Linvi : actually It set `Request.ContentType= null` at server side when I add `Authorization` header in request

Answer (score 0):

Your headers definition looks correct. Have you tried inspecting what is actually get posted, using Fiddler or Chrome dev tools?

Check this one first, and if the post is performed correctly, then it has to do with your model binder on the ASP.NET MVC side.

Comment: When the same thing I'm trying to do using postman, I'm receiving data correctly .  actually when I set the header then It doesn't send the content-Type in request

Comment: That's strange. Is there any chance your $http service gets configured in some way during the app's config phase? Have you tried the same exact approach within a blank angular app?

Comment: yes. Even this is happening in when I try it with ajax request.

Comment: So chances are this is not an issue of angular. Try the following:
- Test the same approach in an incognito window. There are lots of browser plugins which interfere with requests, and you may have one of them installed in your browser.
- Add an 'X-' prefix on the name of the custom header

Comment: actually It set `Request.ContentType= null` at server side when I add `Authorization` header in request .

Comment: There is definitely something off with your system, or your asp.net application configuration. Unfortunately there's not much I can tell you without having access to it.